# Strange Ruby String Selection

Tags: ruby, string

The **string** in question (read from a file):

```
if (true) then
{
  _this = createVehicle ["Land_hut10", [6226.8901, 986.091, 4.5776367e-005], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_10 = _this;
  _this setDir -2.109278;
};
```

Retrieved from a large list of similar (all same file) strings via the following:

```
get_stringR(string,"if","};")
```

And the function code:

```
def get_stringR(a,b,c)
    b = a.index(b)
    b ||= 0
    c = a.rindex(c)
    c ||= b
    r = a[b,c]
    return r
end
```

As so far, this works fine, but what I wanted to do is select the array after "createVehicle", the following (I thought) should work.

```
newstring = get_string(myString,"\[","\];")
```

Note **get_string** is the same as **get_stringR**, except it uses the first occurrence of the pattern both times, rather then the first and last occurrence.

The output should have been:

```
["Land_hut10", [6226.8901, 986.091, 4.5776367e-005], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
```

Instead it was the below, given via 'puts':

```
["Land_hut10", [6226.8901, 986.091, 4.5776367e-005], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_10 = _this;
  _this setDir
```

Some 40 characters past the point it should have retrieve, which was very strange...
Second note, using **both get_string** and **get_stringR** produced the **exact same** result with the parameters given.

I then decided to add the following to my get_string code:

```
   b = a.index(b)
    b ||= 0
    c = a.index(c)
    c ||= b
    if c > 40 then
        c -= 40
    end
    r = a[b,c]
    return r
```

And it works as expected (for every 'block' in the file, even though the strings after that array are not identical in any way), but something obviously isn't right :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want r = a[b..c] instead of r = a[b,c].

Difference is: b..c = start from b, go to c, while b,c = start from b and move c characters to the right.

**Edit:** You don't have to/shouldn't escape the [ and ] either, because you are using strings and not regexen. Also, you have to take the length of the end ("];") into consideration, or you will cut off parts of the end.

```
def get_stringR(a,b,c)
  bp = a.index(b) || 0
  cp = a.rindex(c) || bp
  r = a[bp..cp + c.size - 1]
  return r
end

def get_string(a,b,c)
  bp = a.index(b) || 0
  cp = a.index(c) || bp
  r = a[bp..cp + c.size - 1]
  return r
end
```

Comment: thanks mate! Why c.size? Shouldn't it be a.size? And if so... why?

Comment: If we had the string "abcde" and the delimiters "a" and "de", then the String#index calls would result in the following range:

  abcde
  ^--^ 

That is because String#index returns the starting position of the match.

So we have to add the length of the closing delimiter (minus one) to the end to get the whole substring.

Edit: meh, no newlines/formatting in comments? I hope you get what I mean nevertheless